# Why tensorflow 1.4 does not allow to assign "None" to FLAGS

Tags: tensorflow

I just try to transfer to tensorflow 1.4.

But I noticed that TF1.4 does not support None value flag.

```
FLAGS = tf.app.flags.FLAGS
FLAGS.something = None # ERROR!(in TF1.4)
```

Here is my error.

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/flags.py", line 66, in __setattr__
self._assert_required(name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/flags.py", line 74, in _assert_required
raise AttributeError('Flag --%s must be specified.' % flag_name)
```

It seems that self._assert_required raise an error. (it didn't exist in TF1.3)

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.4/tensorflow/python/platform/flags.py#L66

Why tensorflow 1.4 does not support None value flag? Is there any reason?

Answer (score 0):

As said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33938519/5330223), Tensorflow is trying to make it as close as `python-gflags`. That's why this module is changed like this.

Also look at the commit message

> Add mark_flag_as_required functions to make the APIs compatible with
>   python-gflags.

Details could be found [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/11568).